# removing header comment blocks from *.cpp files

Tags: search, replace, comments

I'm trying now for a while to remove method header comments from a lot of *.cpp files.
I tried many proposals, but never had success.

The cpp comments look like follow:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
* @brief  bla foo
* @param  some param
*/
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Class::Methode1(param) {
}

          // <-- extra newline should be removed too
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
* @fn     thats a function
* @brief  bla foo
* @param  some param
* @return exit code 
*/
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int Class::Methode2(param) {
}
```

I'm searching for an easy way for removing the header including one extra newline between the methods. The lines with "----" don't have always the same number of "-".
Files are in unix file format.

Every command is welcome, as long it runs in Linux.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

ok after a while, i found a way.

I used a perl script:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl -pi
  #multi-line in place substitute - subs.pl
  use strict;
  use warnings;

  BEGIN {undef $/;}

  s|//\-{77}.{1,2}/\*.{1,200}\*/.{1,2}//\-{77}||smg;
```